# Vertical lines in table

Tags: tables, rules

I have the next code, but I want that the vertical line be complete (it's cut off near to horizontal line):

```
\begin{table} [H] \footnotesize 
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\centering
\caption{Massas e percentuais das frações separadas.}

\label{peneiramento}
%\begin{threeparttable}[b]
\begin{tabular}{S[input-symbols = {>},table-format=>2.3]
                S[table-format=4]
                S[table-format=2.1]|
                S[table-format=2]
                S[table-format=2.2,separate-uncertainty=true,table-figures-uncertainty=1]
                S[table-format=1.3,separate-uncertainty=true,table-figures-uncertainty=1]}

\toprule 
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\makecell[tc]{Peneiramento}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\makecell[tc]{Elutriação}} \\
\midrule
{\makecell[tc]{Abertura \\ da peneira \\($\mu m$)}} & {\makecell[tc]{Fração \\ mássica \\ ($g$)}} & {\makecell[tc]{\% \\ massa }} & {\makecell[tc]{Velocidade \\ separação  \\ ($m/s$)}} & {\makecell[tc]{Fração \\ mássica \\ ($g$)}} & {\makecell[tc]{$\%$ \\ massa }}  
\\ 
\midrule

4000 & 26,72 & 34 \\
2830 & 8,79 & 11 \\
1900 & 8,88 & 11 \\
595 & 18,19 & 23 \\
297 & 9,74 & 13 \\
149 & 3,96 & 5 \\
Pan & 1,24 & 2 \\

\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: The rules from the `booktabs` package (`\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, etc.) cut the vertical line by design. The `booktabs` package explicitly says that you should _never_ use vertical rules in tables. If you want them, though, then you need to use other rule commands, like `\hline`.

Comment: ...then you're doing it wrong. Since you're using [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), you should also read the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf). It suggests "Never, ever use vertical rules" (section **2 The layout of formal tables**).

Comment: Maybe the table can be split into *two* tables with horizontal space between them instead of a vertical line.

Answer (score 6):

The table does *not* require vertical line between columns 3 and 4. Just be more deliberate in the way you structure the header material, say, by providing two separate `\cmidrule` statements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{makecell,booktabs,float,siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol,output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H] 
%\footnotesize   % not needed, right?
\centering
\caption{Massas e percentuais das frações separadas.}
\label{peneiramento}

\begin{tabular}{@{}
                S[table-format=4.0]
                S[table-format=2.2]           
                S[table-format=2.0]
                c  % ?
                S[table-format=2.2,
                  separate-uncertainty=true,
                  table-figures-uncertainty=1]
                S[table-format=1.3,
                  separate-uncertainty=true,
                  table-figures-uncertainty=1]
                @{}}

\toprule 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Peneiramento} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Elutriação} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-3} \cmidrule(l){4-6}
{\makecell[tc]{Abertura \\ da peneira \\(\si{\micro\meter})}} & 
{\makecell[tc]{Fração \\ mássica \\ (\si{\gram})}} & 
{\makecell[tc]{\% \\ massa }} & 
{\makecell[tc]{Velocidade \\ separação  \\ 
    (\si{\meter\per\second})}} & 
{\makecell[tc]{Fração \\ mássica \\ (\si{\gram})}} & 
{\makecell[tc]{\% \\ massa }}  
\\ 
\midrule
4000 & 26,72 & 34 \\
2830 &  8,79 & 11 \\
1900 &  8,88 & 11 \\
 595 & 18,19 & 23 \\
 297 &  9,74 & 13 \\
 149 &  3,96 &  5 \\
{Pan}&  1,24 &  2 \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a good answer for this particular problem, but is it possible to have a continuous line in tables generally? What about the cases where it *might* be justified?

Comment: (I’m thinking e.g. [crosstabs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table))

Comment: @svenper - See @Bernard's parallel answer for a solution that features a long vertical line of some sort or other; speaking for myself, I'm not convinced that this table absolutely, positively requires any vertical lines. I agree with the author of the `booktabs` package on the following: If a tableau can't live without vertical lines, one is doing something wrong. BTW, your crosstabs "counterexample" is no counterexample at all: A contingency table can be designed just fine without vertical lines -- and be made more readable in the process. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Vertical lines are not necessarily a bad idea, if used judiciously, but if you want them to intersect the horizontal lines, you have to neutralise the padding that `booktabs` adds around rules, and replace it with ‘cell gapes’ defined by `makecell`. This is done in the first code below.

However, I also propose another code, with a thick vertical grey rule between columns; which looks nicer from my point of view.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, tableportuguese]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}

    \usepackage{array, cellspace, makecell, caption, booktabs}
    \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
    \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}

     \begin{document}

\begin{table} [H] \footnotesize
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}, table-number-alignment=center}
\captionsetup{skip=4pt}
\aboverulesep=0pt
\belowrulesep=0pt
\setcellgapes{0.5ex}\makegapedcells
\renewcommand{\cellalign}{tc}
\centering
\caption{Massas e percentuais das frações separadas.}
\label{peneiramento}
%\begin{threeparttable}[b]
\begin{tabular}{S[input-symbols = {>}, table-format=>2.3]
                S[table-format=4]
                S[table-format=2.1]!{\vrule width 0.08em}
                S[table-format=2]
                S[table-format=2.2,separate-uncertainty=true,table-figures-uncertainty=1]
                S[table-format=1.3,separate-uncertainty=true,table-figures-uncertainty=1]}

\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c!{\vrule width 0.08em}}{\makecell {Peneiramento}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\makecell {Elutriação}} \\
\midrule
{\makecell{Abertura \\ da peneira \\(\si{\um})}}& {\makecell{Fração \\ mássica \\ (g)}} & {\makecell[tc]{\% \\ massa }} & {\makecell{Velocidade \\ separação \\ (\si{\m\per\s})}} & {\makecell {Fração \\ mássica \\ (g)}} & {\makecell { \% \\ massa }}
\\
\midrule
4000 & 26,72 & 34 \\
2830 & 8,79 & 11 \\
1900 & 8,88 & 11 \\
595 & 18,19 & 23 \\
297 & 9,74 & 13 \\
149 & 3,96 & 5 \\
{Pan} & 1,24 & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\vskip1cm
\begin{table} [H] \footnotesize
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}, table-number-alignment=center}
\captionsetup{skip=4pt}
\aboverulesep=-1pt
\belowrulesep=0pt
\cmidrulewidth=0.05em
\setcellgapes{0.5ex}\makegapedcells
\renewcommand{\cellalign}{tc}
\centering
\caption{Massas e percentuais das frações separadas.}
\label{peneiramento}
%\begin{threeparttable}[b]
\begin{tabular}{S[input-symbols = {>}, table-format=>2.3]
                S[table-format=4]
                S[table-format=2.1]!{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule width 0.5em}
                S[table-format=2]
                S[table-format=2.2,separate-uncertainty=true,table-figures-uncertainty=1]
                S[table-format=1.3,separate-uncertainty=true,table-figures-uncertainty=1]}

\toprule
\addlinespace[0.5ex]
\multicolumn{3}{c!{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule width 0.5em}}{\makecell {Peneiramento}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\makecell {Elutriação}} \\
\cmidrule(lr{1em}){1-3}\cmidrule(l{0.5em}r){4-6}
{\makecell{Abertura \\ da peneira \\(\si{\um})}}& {\makecell{Fração \\ mássica \\ (g)}} & {\makecell[tc]{\% \\ massa }} & {\makecell{Velocidade \\ separação \\ (\si{\m\per\s})}} & {\makecell {Fração \\ mássica \\ (g)}} & {\makecell { \% \\ massa }}
\\
\cmidrule(lr{1em}){1-3}\cmidrule(l{0.5em}r){4-6}
4000 & 26,72 & 34 \\
2830 & 8,79 & 11 \\
1900 & 8,88 & 11 \\
595 & 18,19 & 23 \\
297 & 9,74 & 13 \\
149 & 3,96 & 5 \\
{Pan} & 1,24 & 2 \\
\addlinespace[0.8ex]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to use vertical rules with the horizontal rules of `booktabs` you may use the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` which is compatible with the rules of `booktabs`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, tableportuguese]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{table} [H] \footnotesize
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}, table-number-alignment=center}
\captionsetup{skip=4pt}
\centering
\caption{Massas e percentuais das frações separadas.}
\label{peneiramento}
\begin{NiceTabular}{S[input-symbols = {>}, table-format=>2.3]
                S[table-format=4]
                S[table-format=2.1]|
                S[table-format=2]
                S[table-format=2.2,separate-uncertainty=true,table-figures-uncertainty=1]
                S[table-format=1.3,separate-uncertainty=true,table-figures-uncertainty=1]}

\toprule
\Block{1-3}{Peneiramento} &&& \Block{1-3}{Elutriação} \\
\midrule
{\Block{}{Abertura \\ da peneira \\(\si{\um})}}& {\Block{}{Fração \\ mássica \\ (g)}} & {\Block{}{\% \\ massa \\ \\}} &
{\Block{}{Velocidade \\ separação \\ (\si{\m\per\s})}} & {\Block{}{Fração \\ mássica \\ (g)}} & {\Block{}{\% \\
    massa\\ \\}}\\
\midrule
4000 & 26,72 & 34 & & & \\
2830 & 8,79 & 11 \\
1900 & 8,88 & 11 \\
595 & 18,19 & 23 \\
297 & 9,74 & 13 \\
149 & 3,96 & 5 \\
{Pan} & 1,24 & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]